# Get parameters from a href and use them in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am making an ajax servlet-response with 1 servlet and 1 jsp page.
It already works but I always get the same parameters back from my last value of my "a href" which is in c:foreach loop.

as you can see:

```
 <c:forEach items="${row}" var="cell">
<a href="./DokterWeek_KlantoverzichtServlet?AfspraakID=${cell.afspraakId}&Id=${cell.id}&KlantId=${cell.klant.id}" class="popper" data-popbox="pop1">                             
 <script>  var ajaxparameter = 'AfspraakID=${cell.afspraakId}&Id=${cell.id}&KlantId=${cell.klant.id}'; </script> </a>
 </c:forEach>
```

In My javascript:

```
  xmlhttp.open("GET","DokterWeek_KlantoverzichtServlet?" + ajaxparameter,true);
```

So, I tried to put the parameters inside a variable(ajaxparameter) but the variable always contains is the latest "a href " parameters ( Which makes sense because of the c:foreach).

But how can I send these live parameters to my javascript while I hover over the "a href class=popper"

I appreciate any help, been searching for a solution for hours :(

Comment: I am pretty sure that if you put an ID (a counter?) to the `<a>` tag you can retrieve the href attribute from javascript... anyway, I would like to see how is the JS function invoked (how do you get the function to execute, since you do not specify an `onclick` event) to give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need a listener

Long answer: [check this out](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-jsp-custom-tags-enable-h?page=0,0):
this is a great howto to get a messagebubble in your jsp page!

Answer (score 0):

If am understanding it correct, you are calling some javascript function on onHover event for a href tag. If this is correct then in that event handler you read the value of attribute href in javascript variable and strip off parameters from it.

```
<c:forEach items="${row}" var="cell">
<a href="./DokterWeek_KlantoverzichtServlet?AfspraakID=${cell.afspraakId}&Id=${cell.id}&KlantId=${cell.klant.id}" class="popper" data-popbox="pop1" mouseover="setParam(this)">                             
 <script>  var ajaxparameter = 'AfspraakID=${cell.afspraakId}&Id=${cell.id}&KlantId=${cell.klant.id}'; </script> </a>
 </c:forEach>
<script>
function setPara(ele){
var href = ele.href;
var params = href.split('?')[1];
}
</script>
```